# Resources for teaching computer science with R

Tags: programming-languages, education

I am a professor at a university of applied sciences and will teach computer science next semester.

My question is if you know resources which use the [R project](http://www.r-project.org/) as the basis, i.e. not using it primarily for statistics (I do this already in this semester) but for other topics in informatics, mentioned e.g. in this [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_science).

Yet I don't want to go through this list one-by-one but was hoping for a more consistent approach (books, slides, scripts...) covering important parts of the field.

Comment: My flatmate is currently designing a course on R programming for actuarians. I know she looked at three tutorials online (since they could easily be re-distributed at no cost), of which one was based on one other, but eventually ended up buying two O'Reilly books (*R in a Nutshell* and *R Graphics Cookbook*) as inspiration. I'll give you a better answer with references later.

Comment: R is mentioned on the [FSharp Open Source Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/fsharp-opensource) and some of the designers of F# who hang out there note using R with F#; I believe they were in contact with users of R when designing type providers.

Comment: Unqualified gut response: bad idea.

Comment: What is your motivation for using R? If graph theory plays a major role in this course, you should use [igraph](http://igraph.sourceforge.net/) which has a nice R interface.

Comment: @SimonShine: Thank you - I would appreciate that :-)